# Inverted colors in status line. Why?

Tags: vim

I use gvim 7.4 on Windows, clean install, no plugins. Can anybody explain, why this:

```
highlight statusline guifg=red guibg=green
```

will show me green text on red background.

But this one:

```
highlight statusline gui=NONE guifg=red guibg=green
```

will show red text on green background?

(The actual goal was to change the text in statusline from bold to normal. For this task, I added `gui=NONE` and then, see this strange behaviour).

**Edit**

*(As my answer to Kent's comment)*

Here is my complete _vimrc. There are only two lines on code:

```
set laststatus=2
highlight statusline gui=NONE guifg=red guibg=green
```

Also tried:

- `hi` gives the same effect as `highlight`
- `StatusLine` gives the same effect as `statusline`

Comment: The group is called `StatusLine`, I don't know if the case in Windows is ok.... what is the output of `:hi StatusLine` also, did you define highlighting of `User1-9`? what did you set in your `statusline`? show your vimrc

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited the question

Comment: @Carpetsmoker what is the output of `:hi StatusLine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default `StatusLine` is:

```
:hi StatusLine
  StatusLine     xxx term=bold,reverse cterm=bold,reverse gui=bold,reverse
```

Notice the `reverse` keyword in `cterm` and `gui`? That tells it to use reverse video.

This is also why the colours are what you expect if you use `gui=NONE` (or `gui=bold`).

> hi gives the same effect as highlight

`hi` is just the abbreviated version of `highlight`.

Answer (score 4):

To check how was a hi-group defined, in vim use: `hi GroupName`, that's why I keep asking OP and Carpetsmoker to provide their cmd output.

After vim has been compiled and installed, some default HL-Groups have been already defined.

From time to time people asked about the default color scheme. And want to extend the "default" color scheme.  The location is easy to find, on a linux box, e.g. it locates at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/default.vim`, different distributions could have different paths.

However if we open the `default.vim`, we will see a rather simple vim file. No any HL definition. Because they were in vim source codes as default defined.

Regarding the `StatusLine` group, it was defined in `syntax.c` file:

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/8bc189e81aa98ba4aebb03a9dc9527a210fce816/src/syntax.c#L6784

We can see that the `reverse` is in `StatusLine` and `StatusLineNC` groups.

To get rid of the reverse "feature", you have to overwrite the `gui` or `cterm` attribute.